# JQuery grep - returning data with 2 parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

So I have an array of objects, many of which have duplicate key properties, since some are dynamically created replications with a few, non-specific fields subject to change.

```
var myArray = [
{Name: Object1, Version:1, TimeCreated: 1:00, Quantity: 3},
{Name: Object1, Version:2, TimeCreated: 13:00, Quantity: 8},
{Name: Object1, Version:3, TimeCreated: 14:00, Quantity: 13},
{Name: Object2, Version:1, TimeCreated: 1:00, Quantity: 5},
{Name: Object2, Version:2, TimeCreated: 4:00, Quantity: 3},
{Name: Object3, Version:1, TimeCreated: 1:00, Quantity: 2};
]
```

myArray is used to create tables rows on a page, with table data for each property.

I have an array of table rows as well, including all but the last version of each object. So `tableRows[]` would include the `<tr>`s created by `Object1` versions 1 and 2 and `Object2` version 1.

I now need to cycle through and select specific objects out of this array based on both their name and version, so that I can compare the two Arrays based on both properties.  Both are keys here, since Version 1 and 2 and Object1 and Object2 are not specific in themselves.  Here is how I have tried

```
for (x in myArray){
  var newArray;

  for (r in myArray){
    newArray = $.grep(tableRows, function(e) {
       return (e.Name == 'Object' + r &&
               e.Version == x);
    })
    //code to assess relation to the other objects in myArray with newArray
  }
}
```

Right now I am just hammering down my understanding of `$.grep` and i am wonder if I am overreaching the intent or use of it. Can I even assess two conditions like that?

Comment: It can compare any number of properties/values, however you don't appear to be storing the result of this filtering anywhere.

Comment: Oh, forgot to include that in the sample. I declare another variable in the first array , var newArray, which is then set as newArray = $.grep....